# Indian music lyrics spammer

Tags: discussion, spam, abuse, copyright-infringement

This spammer has been hitting various Stack Exchange sites with multiple spam posts over the last couple of days:

https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?body=givemelyrics.com

The current search results show a couple of spams to Ask Ubuntu a couple of days ago, then another 5 during yesterday, and now another 4 so far today. (Each hit in the search result is a link to an archived spam post. Most of these are now deleted by helpful users and moderators, but the evidence for the ones which have been reported to Metasmoke are archived there.)

Reverse IP indicates that this spammer is currently hosted by Cloudflare, a popular content delivery / load balancing / attack protection provider.  The [whois registration](https://who.is/whois/givemelyrics.com) is similarly behind an anonymizer service.  Visiting the site reveals no contact information, though it seems likely that some of the content is in violation of applicable copyrights.

I am collecting these notes here to hopefully help coordinate contacts with the upstream providers. I have contacted Cloudflare via their [abuse form](https://www.cloudflare.com/abuse/form) and requested for the complaint to be sent with my contact information to the perp's upstream provider, and without my contact details to the perp.

To nominally turn this into a question, can anybody dig up better contact information for the spam site and their hosting provider?

Comment: A complaint to Cloudflare would seem to be in order.  https://www.cloudflare.com/abuse/.  They will forward the complaint to the originating hosting provider.

Comment: I emailed them earlier today, like I wrote in the post, but if I don't get at least an automated reply within a few hours I'll submit the form as well. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I submitted their form now, and updated the post accordingly.